# What happens at Screen Lock?

Tags: android, flash, camera, locking, screen-lock

I am working with **Camera API** to develop an android app. I use **flash** in this app and I need it to be **ON** all the time. I managed to turn **flash ON** at start, and after `onResume()` is called, but I can't figure out what to do after a **screen lock**. When I lock my screen and then unlock it, flash doesnt turn **ON**.

I need to understand how to manage that and turn **flash ON after unlocking** the screen if the app is running(not `onPause()`).

Any reference or advice is welcome! Thanks in advance!